# Jacobi Method & Basic Matrix Math using NUMPY

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting an import error for "norm". What am I not doing correct??

I'm open to constructive feedback on improving the code, however I have to keep the parameters as they are!

Thanks!!!

Code is below:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import norm, inalg, array, zeros, diag, diagflat, dot, linalg

"""Test Case Data"""

 A = np.matrix([[4,-1,-1],[-2,6,1],[-1,1,7]])
 b = np.matrix([[3],[9],[-6]])
 x = np.matrix([[0],[0],[0]])


"""Main Function"""
def jacobi(A, b, x, Tolerance, Iterations):

    V = np.diag(A)
    D = np.diag(V)
    R = D-A
    D_I = D.I
    D = np.asmatrix(D)

    Counter_1 = 1
    tol_gauge = 100

    while Counter_1 <= Iterations:
    # I considered using the "dot" function in NUMPY but I was wary of mixed results


         iterative_approach_form = D_I * ((R*x)+b)
         tol_gauge = np.linalg.norm(iterative_approach_form-x)
         x = iterative_approach_form

    if initial_tol <= Tolerance:
        return("The Solution x = {},y={}, z={} ".format(x[0], x[1], x[2]))
        return("The Solution was found in %s interation(s)" %(Counter_1))

    else: 
        pass
    Counter_1 +=1
return("The Solution was not found in {} iteration(s)".format(Iterations))
```

Comment: Could you check the function name after norm, it looks like there is a syntax error there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which numpy module you are importing from. The following works if you want to use a function only by its name:

```
from numpy import linalg
from numpy.linalg import norm
from numpy import zeros, array, diag, diagflat, dot
```

Looking at you code however, you don't need the second import line, because in the rest of the code the numpy functions are specified according to the accepted norm. For example, norm is already present in your code as np.linalg.norm.

There are three more issues with your code: 1) initial_tol is not assigned a value; 2) tol_gauge is assigned but not used in the code; 3) the last return statement is not indented properly (perhaps only here) and the same is very likely for the block in your while loop.

Comment: Thanks that works! Yes the scope is somewhat off as I admittedly haven't gotten used to pasting in code here in SO so it may have just come in a little off. The scope in my IDE is correct though! Thanks again for help!